# is there a way to retrieve a single row's column in a database table in laravel's database query builder

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to get the last user's record for a single column to add to another column from a different table

i tried coding like so

```
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'accnumber' => 'required',
            'amt_debit' => 'required',
            'bankname' => 'required',
            'swift_code' => 'required',
            'Remarks' => 'required',
            'acc_type' => 'required',    
        ]);

        // auth()->user()->funds()->create($data);

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $debit = DB::table('funds')->where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('amt_debit')->latest()
        ->first();

        $amt = DB::table('accounts.balance')->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

        $sum = $debit + $amt;

        echo $sum;
    }
```

please i need understanding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the sum code like this :

```
$sum = $debit->amt_debit + $amt->balance;
```

Because when you select one column it will return like this :

```
attributes: array:1 [
    "amt_debit" => "your amount"
]
```

So you need to call that one column from your class.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a single value, a single column from a row, there is the `value` method:

```
$debit =  DB::table('funds')
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->latest()
    ->value('amt_debit');

$amt = DB::table('accounts')
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->value('balance');
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results) `value`